# How to solve Unhandled Exception: A DashboardService was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below screen which contains the sort part:

[image: Sort Part]

So the problem now when I am fast clicking on any items in the sort part before the sort disappears, I found the below error with a frozen or black screen.

```
E/flutter ( 6099): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: A DashboardService was used after being disposed.
E/flutter ( 6099): Once you have called dispose() on a DashboardService, it can no longer be used.
```

and this is the bottom menu I have:

```
import 'package:BOTS/globals/localize.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/widgets/forms/heightSpacer.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/widgets/label.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/widgets/revenyouDivider.dart';

import '../../backend/backend.dart';
import '../../globals/constants.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/pages/dashboard/dashboardService.dart';

class DashboardOptionsBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final DashboardService dashboardService;
  const DashboardOptionsBottomSheet({
    Key key,
    this.dashboardService,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState createState() =>
      DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState(dashboardService);
}

class DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState
    extends State<DashboardOptionsBottomSheet> {
  final DashboardService dashboardService;

  DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState(this.dashboardService);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _segmentWidth = (_width - 50.0) / 3;

    String results = Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.results");
    String newest = Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.newest");
    String amount = Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.amount");
    var sharedValue = 0;
    final bold = FontWeight.w700;
    final med = FontWeight.w500;
    FontWeight _resultsWeight = med;
    FontWeight _newestWeight = med;
    FontWeight _amountWeight = med;

    Map<int, Widget> segmentMap() {
      return <int, Widget>{
        0: Container(
          height: 37,
          width: _segmentWidth,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Label(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: results,
                  size: 14,
                  fontWeight: _resultsWeight,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
        1: Container(
          height: 37,
          width: _segmentWidth,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Label(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: newest,
                  size: 14,
                  fontWeight: _newestWeight,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
        2: Container(
          height: 37,
          width: _segmentWidth,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Label(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: amount,
                  size: 14,
                  fontWeight: _amountWeight,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      };
    }

    SortedBy sortedBy = dashboardService.sortedBy;
    switch (sortedBy) {
      case SortedBy.results:
        sharedValue = 0;
        _resultsWeight = bold;
        _newestWeight = med;
        _amountWeight = med;
        break;
      case SortedBy.newest:
        sharedValue = 1;
        _resultsWeight = med;
        _newestWeight = bold;
        _amountWeight = med;
        break;
      case SortedBy.amount:
        sharedValue = 2;
        _resultsWeight = med;
        _newestWeight = med;
        _amountWeight = bold;
        break;
    }
    String _sorted;

    return Material(
      child: Container(
        height: 380,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(contrastColor3),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            HeightSpacer(height: 30),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: TitleLabel(
                    text: Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.sortBy"),
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
              child: Container(
                child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                  children: segmentMap(),
                  onValueChanged: (int val) {
                    sharedValue = val;
                    SortedBy sortedBy;
                    switch (val) {
                      case 0:
                        sortedBy = SortedBy.results;
                        _sorted = "results";

                        _newestWeight = med;
                        _amountWeight = med;
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        sortedBy = SortedBy.newest;
                        _sorted = "newest";
                        _resultsWeight = med;

                        _amountWeight = med;
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        sortedBy = SortedBy.amount;
                        _sorted = "amount";
                        _resultsWeight = med;
                        _newestWeight = med;

                        break;
                    }
                    dashboardService.clearStrategies();

                    dashboardService.sortedBy = sortedBy;
                    prefs.sortedBy = _sorted;
                    dashboardService
                        .getBalanceData(dashboardService.showCrypto);
                    dashboardService.fetchAllStrategies();
                    setState(() {});
                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    });
                  },
                  groupValue: sharedValue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 20),
            RevenYouDivider(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 30),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: TitleLabel(
                    text:
                        Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.display"),
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: Label(
                    text: Localize.of(context)
                        .trans("dashboardOptions.showGraphs"),
                    size: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: Switch(
                    value: dashboardService.showGraphs,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      dashboardService.clearStrategies();
                      dashboardService.showGraphs = val;
                      prefs.showGraphs = val;
                      dashboardService
                          .getBalanceData(dashboardService.showCrypto);
                      dashboardService.fetchAllStrategies();

                      // Update the switch UI, then pop the bottomsheet after a delay
                      setState(() {});
                      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      });
                    },
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    activeTrackColor: Color(primaryColor5),
                    inactiveTrackColor: Color(contrastColor2),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            RevenYouDivider(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: Label(
                    text: Localize.of(context)
                        .trans("dashboardOptions.showCrypto"),
                    size: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: Switch(
                    value: dashboardService.showCrypto,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      dashboardService.clearStrategies();
                      dashboardService.showCrypto = val;
                      prefs.showCrypto = val;
                      dashboardService.getBalanceData(val);
                      dashboardService.fetchAllStrategies();

                      // Update the switch UI, then pop the bottomsheet after a delay
                      setState(() {});
                      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      });
                    },
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    activeTrackColor: Color(primaryColor5),
                    activeThumbImage: AssetImage(
                      "assets/artwork/crypto/crypto.webp",
                    ),
                    inactiveThumbImage: AssetImage(
                      "assets/artwork/euro/euro.webp",
                    ),
                    inactiveTrackColor: Color(contrastColor2),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            RevenYouDivider(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            ),
            Container(height: 20),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the `dashBoardService`

```
DashboardService() {
    showCrypto = prefs.showCrypto;
    showGraphs = prefs.showGraphs;

    final sort = prefs.sortedBy;
    switch (sort) {
      case "results":
        sortedBy = SortedBy.results;
        break;
      case "newest":
        sortedBy = SortedBy.newest;
        break;
      case "amount":
        sortedBy = SortedBy.amount;
        break;
    }

    _initFetchTimer();
    _initCheckCryptoTimer();

    // fetch the latest langauge updates when the user is logged in
    languageService.updateLangaugeInApp();
  }
```

and this is the full part to DashBOardService();

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:BOTS/backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/backend/models/dashboardData.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/backend/models/strategy.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/backend/models/totalBalance.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/backend/models/totalPortfolio.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/globals/localize.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/helpers/localAuthHelper.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/widgets/platform_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/extensions/iterablesExtensions.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/extensions/doubleExtensions.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

enum StrategyType { active, pending, closed }
enum SortedBy { results, newest, amount }

class DashboardService extends ChangeNotifier {
  Timer _fetchTimer;
  Timer _cryptoTimer;

  DashboardPortfolioData portfolioData;
  List<Strategy> activeStrategies = [];
  List<Strategy> pendingStrategies = [];
  List<dynamic> closedStrategies = [];
  List<TotalBalance> cardDetails = [];

  double euroAmount = 0.0;

  var activeHasBeenFetched = false;
  var pendingHasBeenFetched = false;
  var closedHasBeenFetched = false;

  var showGetStartedPage = false;

  var showTotalPortfolioSpinner = true;
  var showActiveCardSpinners = true;
  var showPendingCardSpinners = true;
  var closedStrategiesLoading = true;

  bool ignoreSwitchTap = true;
  bool _fetchingAll = false;
  bool showCrypto = false;
  bool showGraphs = true;
  bool userHasBalances = false;

  String totalBalance;
  String availableBalance;

  double scrollOffset = 0.0;
  double scrollAmount;

  /// the current selected strategy tab on the dashboard.
  /// when the timer completes the strategy tab will get
  /// refreshed
  StrategyType selectedStrategyTab = StrategyType.active;
  SortedBy sortedBy = SortedBy.results;

  TabController tabBarViewController;

  DashboardService() {
    showCrypto = prefs.showCrypto;
    showGraphs = prefs.showGraphs;

    final sort = prefs.sortedBy;
    switch (sort) {
      case "results":
        sortedBy = SortedBy.results;
        break;
      case "newest":
        sortedBy = SortedBy.newest;
        break;
      case "amount":
        sortedBy = SortedBy.amount;
        break;
    }

    _initFetchTimer();
    _initCheckCryptoTimer();

    // fetch the latest langauge updates when the user is logged in
    languageService.updateLangaugeInApp();
  }

  void _initFetchTimer() {
    _fetchTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (_) async {
      if (!data.isLoggedOn) {
        _fetchTimer.cancel();
        return;
      }

      await clearStrategies();
      await fetchPortfolioData(isCrypto: showCrypto, showGraphs: showGraphs);
      fetchAllStrategies();
    });
  }

  void _initCheckCryptoTimer() {
    bool _showCrypto = showCrypto;
    _cryptoTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (_) async {
      if (_showCrypto != prefs.showCrypto) {
        await forceRefresh();
        await getBalanceData(prefs.showCrypto);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<DashboardPortfolioData> fetchPortfolioData({
    bool isCrypto = false,
    bool showGraphs = true,
  }) async {
    String exchange = "all";
    String asset = "";
    bool paper = false;

    ignoreSwitchTap = true;
    showTotalPortfolioSpinner = true;
    notifyListeners();

    portfolioData = await payment.getTotalPortfolioAndBalances(
      exchange,
      asset,
      paper,
      isCrypto: isCrypto,
    );

    showGetStartedPage = _shouldShowGetStartedPage();

    prefs.showGetStarted = showGetStartedPage;

    prefs.showGraphs = showGraphs;

    showTotalPortfolioSpinner = false;

    notifyListeners();

    return portfolioData;
  }

  bool _shouldShowGetStartedPage() {
    final totalBalance =
        portfolioData?.totalPortfolio?.totalBalance?.parseToDouble();
    final pendingBalance =
        portfolioData?.totalPortfolio?.pendingBalance?.parseToDouble();
    final withdrawableBalance =
        portfolioData?.totalPortfolio?.withdrawableBalance?.parseToDouble();
    final availableBalance =
        portfolioData?.totalPortfolio?.availableBalance?.parseToDouble();
    final avialableBalanceYouhex =
        portfolioData?.totalPortfolio?.availableBalanceYouhex?.parseToDouble();
    final avialableBalanceGalaex =
        portfolioData?.totalPortfolio?.availableBalanceGalaex?.parseToDouble();

    return totalBalance == 0.0 &&
        (activeStrategies?.length ?? 0) == 0 &&
        pendingBalance == 0.0 &&
        withdrawableBalance == 0.0 &&
        availableBalance == 0.0 &&
        avialableBalanceYouhex == 0.0 &&
        avialableBalanceGalaex == 0.0 &&
        (pendingStrategies?.length ?? 0) == 0;
  }

  /// Select the type of strategies to load using an enum.
  /// The [tabChanged] flag is used to prevent over requesting of strategies when the tab
  /// changes in the dashboard. The exception to this rule is if the tab is selected for the first time.
  Future fetchStrategies({
    @required StrategyType strategyType,
    bool tabChanged = false,
  }) async {
    switch (strategyType) {
      case StrategyType.active:
        if (tabChanged && activeHasBeenFetched) {
          return;
        }

        activeHasBeenFetched = true;
        showActiveCardSpinners = true;
        ignoreSwitchTap = true;
        notifyListeners();

        // sort the returned strategy list
        final unsortedStrategies =
            await subscribeBot.activeStrategy(showCrypto: showCrypto);

        activeStrategies = await sortStrategies(unsortedStrategies);

        activeStrategies = await sortStrategies(unsortedStrategies);

        // refresh the dashboard for a final time to turn off the loading spinners
        showActiveCardSpinners = false;
        if (!_fetchingAll) ignoreSwitchTap = false;
        notifyListeners();

        break;

      case StrategyType.pending:
        if (tabChanged && pendingHasBeenFetched) {
          return;
        }

        pendingHasBeenFetched = true;

        showPendingCardSpinners = true;
        ignoreSwitchTap = true;
        notifyListeners();

        pendingStrategies = await subscribeBot.pendingStrategy();

        showPendingCardSpinners = false;
        if (!_fetchingAll) ignoreSwitchTap = false;
        notifyListeners();

        break;

      case StrategyType.closed:
        if (tabChanged && closedHasBeenFetched) {
          return;
        }

        closedHasBeenFetched = true;

        closedStrategiesLoading = true;
        ignoreSwitchTap = true;
        notifyListeners();

        final closedItems =
            await subscribeBot.stoppedStrategy(showCrypto: showCrypto);

        closedItems.sort((x, y) => x.dateStopped.compareTo(y.dateStopped));

        final groupedItems =
            closedItems.reversed.groupBy((x) => x.formattedDateStopped);

        closedStrategies = [];

        groupedItems.forEach((key, value) {
          closedStrategies.add(key);
          closedStrategies.addAll(value);
        });

        closedStrategiesLoading = false;
        if (!_fetchingAll) ignoreSwitchTap = false;
        notifyListeners();

        break;
    }
  }

  Future fetchAllStrategies() async {
    _fetchingAll = true;
    showActiveCardSpinners = true;
    showPendingCardSpinners = true;
    closedStrategiesLoading = true;
    ignoreSwitchTap = true;
    notifyListeners();

    for (StrategyType type in StrategyType.values) {
      await fetchStrategies(strategyType: type);
    }

    _fetchingAll = false;
    ignoreSwitchTap = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return;
  }

  Future<List<Strategy>> sortStrategies(List<Strategy> unsortedList) async {
    if (unsortedList == null) {
      return [];
    }
    var newList = unsortedList;

    if (sortedBy == SortedBy.results) {
      newList.sort((b, a) => a.percentageChange.compareTo(b.percentageChange));
    } else if (sortedBy == SortedBy.amount) {
      newList.sort((b, a) => a.totalAmount.compareTo(b.totalAmount));
    } else if (sortedBy == SortedBy.newest) {
      newList.sort((b, a) => a.dateSubbed.compareTo(b.dateSubbed));
    }
    return newList;
  }

  void clearStrategies() async {
    activeStrategies = null;
    pendingStrategies = null;
    closedStrategies = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<TotalPortfolio> updateTotalBalance() async {
    final result =
        await fetchPortfolioData(isCrypto: showCrypto, showGraphs: showGraphs);

    portfolioData.totalPortfolio = result.totalPortfolio;

    return portfolioData.totalPortfolio;
  }

  Future getBalanceData(bool isCrypto) async {
    final portAndBalance =
        await fetchPortfolioData(isCrypto: isCrypto, showGraphs: showGraphs);

    if (!isCrypto) {
      euroAmount =
          portfolioData?.totalBalances?.firstOrNull?.totalAmount ?? 0.00;
    }

    totalBalance = portAndBalance.totalPortfolio.totalBalance;
    availableBalance = portAndBalance.totalPortfolio.availableBalance;

    if (portAndBalance.totalBalances.length > 0) {
      userHasBalances = true;
    } else {
      userHasBalances = false;
    }

    cardDetails = portAndBalance.totalBalances;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future initBalanceData(bool isCrypto) async {
    await getBalanceData(false);
    euroAmount = portfolioData?.totalBalances?.firstOrNull?.totalAmount ?? 0.00;

    if (isCrypto) await getBalanceData(true);
  }

  void forceRefresh() async {
    await clearStrategies();
    _fetchTimer.cancel();
    _cryptoTimer.cancel();

    showCrypto = prefs.showCrypto;
    fetchPortfolioData(isCrypto: showCrypto);

    fetchAllStrategies();
    _initFetchTimer();
    _initCheckCryptoTimer();
  }

  void setScrollAmount(double amount) {
    scrollAmount = amount;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setScrollOffset(double offset) {
    scrollOffset = offset;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future askToUseBiometrics(BuildContext context) async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0), () async {
      final canCheckBiometrics = await LocalAuthHelper.canCheckBiometrics();

      if (!canCheckBiometrics) {
        return;
      }

      if (prefs.biometrics || prefs.userAskedToEnableBiometrics) {
        return;
      }

      var idString = Localize.of(context).trans("biometrics.touchID");

      var permissionContent =
          Localize.of(context).trans("biometrics.permissionContentTouchID");

      if (await LocalAuthHelper.faceIDAvailable()) {
        idString = Localize.of(context).trans("biometrics.faceID");
        permissionContent =
            Localize.of(context).trans("biometrics.permissionContentFaceID");
      }

      if (canCheckBiometrics) {
        await PlatformAlertDialog(
          title: "${permissionContent} ${idString}?",
          content: permissionContent,
          cancelActionText:
              Localize.of(context).trans("biometrics.permissionCancelButton"),
          defaultActionText: Localize.of(context).trans("verifyId.ok"),
          onActionButtonTapped: () async {
            prefs.biometrics = true;
            prefs.userAskedToEnableBiometrics = true;
          },
        ).show(context);
        prefs.userAskedToEnableBiometrics = true;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _fetchTimer.cancel();
    _cryptoTimer.cancel();
  }
}
```

and this is the below DeBug state:

[image: DeBug Desc]

I hope this information will be clear enough and let me know if there's something missing

Comment: you can override the dispose method and check it on your end when exactly it gets called

Comment: @jitsm555 thanks a lot for you support I didn't get you could you help me to do this, if you have time :), thank you

Comment: stateful widget have dispose method, just override it and print statement there, that's it. now you can check the print statement on console, see there when it's gets called. You will find cause of it.

Comment: @jitsm555 thanks a lot for your comment I have added the dashBoardService(); :D